# Regex Help - Match any URL Parameter & Value not in List

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics, url-parameters, universal-analytics

Thank you for looking at this!

I am trying to build some Regex that works in JavaScript that will match ALL URL parameters and their values that are not in my predefined list.  Example:

Raw URL:

```
/folder/index.html?knownParamA=1234&unknownParamA=1234&knownParamB=1234&unknownParamB=1234
```

My List of Know Parameters:

```
((knownParamA|knownParamB|knownParamC)=[^&]*&?)/gi
```

Resulting (Cleaned up) URL:

```
/folder/index.html?knownParamA=1234&unknownParam=1234
```

Ultimately, I want to capture a cleaned up version of any URL with only the parameters and values I need.  There's tons of parameters on my website that are meaningless to me and only get in the way.  One solution I found required a look back but I don't think JavaScript supports those.

Thank you so much for the help!!!

**Solution Based on Feedback Below:**

```
pageURL = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
knownParams = 'knownParamA|knownParamB|knownParamC|knownParamD';

var urlCleanerRegexStep1 = new RegExp('[?&](?!(?:' + knownParams + ')(?==))[^=]+=[^&]*', 'gi');
var urlCleanerRegexStep2 = new RegExp('[?&]([^=]+=[^&]*)', '');
cleanPageURL = pageURL.replace(urlCleanerRegexStep1, "").replace(urlCleanerRegexStep2, '?$1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative searches are tricky, and *require* zero-width lookaheads.

This will find the unknown parameters and strip them out of the URL: *(Update 2: This doesn't keep unknown parameters **that start with known parameters** any more.)*

```
step1 = url.replace(/[?&](?!(?:knownParamA|knownParamB)(?==))[^=]+=[^&]*/gi, '');
// "/folder/index.html?knownParamA=1234&knownParamB=1234"
```

However, if the *first* parameter gets stripped out, your first remaining parameter will be preceded by a `&` instead of a `?`, and you will need to replace that too:

```
clean = step1.replace(/[?&]([^=]+=[^&]*)/, '?$1');
// "/folder/index.html?knownParamA=1234&knownParamB=1234"
```

You can chain these together, of course:

```
clean = url.replace(/[?&](?!(?:knownParamA|knownParamB)(?==))[^=]+=[^&]*/gi, '').
  replace(/[?&]([^=]+=[^&]*)/, '?$1');
```

---

Update: I have included [user3842539](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3842539/user3842539)'s expansion of the code, as it's easier to read here than in a comment.

```
pageURL = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
knownParams = 'knownParamA|knownParamB|knownParamC|knownParamD';
var urlCleanerRegexStep1 = new RegExp('[?&](?!(?:' + knownParams + ')(?==))[^=]+=[^&]*', 'gi');
var urlCleanerRegexStep2 = new RegExp('[?&]([^=]+=[^&]*)', '');
cleanPageURL = pageURL.replace(urlCleanerRegexStep1, '').replace(urlCleanerRegexStep2, '?$1');
```

---

To help you interpret these regexes:

- `[?&]` = either `?` or `&`
- `(`...`)` = captured group
- `(?!`...`)` = not followed by a match for this group
- `(?:`...`)` = uncaptured group
- `(?=`...`)` = followed by a match for this group
- `=` = `=`
- `[^=]` = any character other than `=`
- `+` = one or more times
- `[^&]` = any character other than `&`
- `*` = zero or more times

Outside the regex body,

- The `g` flag means 'all matches' (as opposed to only the first)
- The `i` flag means 'case-insensitive'
- In the replacement string, `$1` means 'captured group 1'

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response!  This looks great and I'm testing it out the first example now.  Hopefully I will see some positive results in the morning.  Can you give me explanation around the second one (clean =step1.replace...)?  Not sure I'm following how the question mark gets removed.  Could there be something added to the first example to exclude question marks or start the look forward after the question mark?  Man, that's some crazy looking regex. :)

Comment: The first regex matches the `?` or `&` before each parameter, because the lookahead (`(?!`...`)`) needs something to look ahead *of*. I tried attaching a look-behind to the `=` instead, but you're right, Javascript doesn't do those.

Comment: Thanks, PJSCopeland!  Can i still get a copy of what you were trying to do?  I can try plugging it into Google Analytics and see what happens.  It's worth a shot.

Comment: What you all provided was spot on.  Thanks!  I took the liberty to make it look a little more friendly for anyone else that might need this in the future.

pageURL = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
knownParams = 'knownParamA|knownParamB|knownParamC|knownParamD';
var urlCleanerRegexStep1 = new RegExp('[?&](?!' + knownParams + ')[^=]+=[^&]*', 'gi');
var urlCleanerRegexStep2 = new RegExp('[?&]([^=]+=[^&]*)', '');
cleanPageURL = pageURL.replace(urlCleanerRegexStep1, "").replace(urlCleanerRegexStep2, '?$1');

Comment: And, FYI to Google Anayltics users trying to use this:  You can't use Regex Lookaheads in Filters.  If you want to use this then use JavaScript in your tag management system or place directly into the GA code on the website.

Comment: Here's a look-behind version that works in Ruby: `url.gsub(/[^?&=]+(?<![?&](?:knownParamA|knownParamB))=[^&]*&?/i, '')` It will keep a `&` at the end unless the last parameter is known, but I think that's still a valid URL. For Javascript, use `replace(/`...`/g, '')` instead of `gsub(/`...`/, '')`.

Comment: One issue I found with the solution is if I have a one character parameter "s" in my list of known parameters and I have an unknown parameter of "site" it will match both. So, I'm trying to figure out how to put word boundaries around the list, but so far no luck. If I can come up with a solution or someone else can i will gladly add it to the original post.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for a `?` or `&`, not followed by any of your known params *followed by `=`.* Try `var urlCleanerRegexStep1 = new RegExp('[?&](?!(?:' + knownParams + ')(?==))[^=]+=[^&]*', 'gi');`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  YES, this is it!  Thank you so much!  You are a Regex Ninja for sure.

Comment: Just an update.  I found that if you remove "[^=]+=" from urlCleanerRegexStep1 it will also match some additional garbage in the URL, like parameters that don't have an equal sign and a value.  A real example I had was a form field that put the results in a URL parameter.  The regex worked up until a user used the "&" symbol in a sentence.  Of course there was no "=" sign proceeding it because it was a sentence.  The change I am referencing here seems to also match this case too.  Hope someone finds this useful.